# Show the set of ordinals less than a certain cardinal is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, ordinals

Sorry for the incomplete title; it would become too long.
The question is as follows: for the ordinal $\omega$, consider the equation card $\omega$ $\lt$ card $\xi$ $\leq$ card $2^\omega$. Denote the minimum element of the set of ordinals $\xi$ satisfying the previous equation as $\Omega$. Denote the set $\Omega'$ as the set of all ordinals less than or equal to $\Omega$.

I need to show that the set $\Omega'$ is uncountable. However, I am having trouble understanding the question and figuring out the steps I need to take to solve the problem, as it is impossible (I believe) to characterize $\xi$, and I am fairly new to set theory.

Any detailed help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want $\Omega'$ to be the set of *cardinals* $\le\Omega$? If so, it's definitely **not** uncountable: $\Omega$ is just the first uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$, and the only cardinals below it are the finite cardinals and $\omega$. If you mean $\Omega'$ to be the set of *ordinals* $<\Omega$, this is just asking you to show that there are uncountably many countable ordinals, albeit phrased in a very confusing way. (Also, $2^\omega$ doesn't seem to be playing any role here. Are you sure you copied the problem correctly?)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Apologies - you are right. It is the set of ordinals $\leq$ $\Omega$. I will fix that. And yes - I think the question is asking to show that there are uncountably many countable ordinals (which I could not understand, because, as you mentioned, it is phrased in a very confusing way).

Comment: And it seems that the question has already been asked elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be the minimal solution of the equation $(\star)$: card $\omega <$ card $\Omega < $ card $2^\omega$.

Recall that for any ordinal $\beta$ we have
$$ \{\alpha \in \mathbb{Ord} : \alpha < \beta\}=\beta.$$

Therefore $$\Omega' = \{\alpha \in \mathbb{Ord} : \alpha < \Omega\}\cup \{\Omega\}=\Omega \cup \{\Omega\}$$ and therefore card $\Omega' = $ card $\Omega> $ card $\omega$ and thus $\Omega'$ is uncountable.